# React Native (expo) and Firebase Firestore - Issue when a user is created within the app (Undefined is not an object...evaluating...)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am having trouble with firebase and expo. When we do the signup process, and the user is generated through firebase, we sometimes get "undefined is not an object (evaluating 0.docs[0].data)" and the user is redirected to the entry point of the application instead of going to the next screen.

Most of the users will be able to go through the process without any problem. But few reported the same issues, and I have seen that with one account.

Here below the function that does not work properly

```js
const createUser = async () => {
    //Check if user already exists
    await props.firebase.db
      .collection('users')
      .where('email', '==', props.userProfile.email)
      .get()
      .then(async (snapShot) => {
        //if no document is found, save user to db
        if (snapShot.docs.length === 0) {
          await saveUserToDataBase()
            .then(() => {
              setShowLoader(false);
              props.navigation.navigate('NotificationPermission');
            })
            .catch((err) => Alert.alert('An error occurred', err.message));
        }
        //else log an error, TODO: add error text in app.
        else {
          setShowLoader(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        Alert.alert('An error occurred', err.message);
      });
  };
```

```js
 const saveUserToDataBase = async () => {
    //finds the correct collection and creates a new document within in containing the profile data.
    await props.firebase.db
      .collection('users')
      .add({
        first_name: props.userProfile.firstName,
        email: props.userProfile.email.toLowerCase(),
        phone_number: props.userProfile.phoneNumber,
        organization: props.userProfile.organization,
        profileId: props.userProfile.profileId,
      })
      .then(async (docRef) => {
        await props.firebase.db
          .collection('profile')
          .doc(props.userProfile.profileId)
          .update({
            user_id: docRef.id,
          })
          .then(async () => {
            await uploadProfilePhoto(docRef.id);
            if (props.accessToken) {
              props.navigation.navigate('NotificationPermission');
            } else {
              props.navigation.navigate('NotificationPermission');
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            Alert.alert(
              'An error occurred updating the users profile ',
              err.message,
            );
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        Alert.alert('An error occurred creating the user', err.message);
      });
  };
```

I have used the Alert component to check the error directly, the error is consistent with few email addresses. I have upgraded the firebase package, did no do anything. 
I feel like the `onAuthStateChanged` could be responsible of that but I am not sure how to handle that? Your help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any log generated on serverside when this error ocurs? if there is a log could you share it please?

Comment: also is there a pattern on the users giving the error?